# Python logging sometimes writing message to file but not format

Tags: python, logging

Having a new problem where the logger is writing about every other line without the format, just the message.

My code:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

# Set up logging
LOG_FILE = argv[0][:-3] + '.log'
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=LOG_FILE,
    filemode='a',
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE,maxBytes=1000000)
logger.addHandler(handler)

def main():
    target, command, notify_address, wait = get_args(argv)
    logger.info('Checking status of %s every %d minutes.' % (target, wait))
    logger.info('Running %s and sending output to %s when online.' % (command, notify_address))
```

The vars returned from get_args() are all strings, even though wait is a number.

Note that I am not receiving any errors in my IDE or when running.

The output I am getting in my log file:

```
2015-02-12 16:26:27,483 - INFO - Checking status of <ip address> every 30 minutes.
Running <arbitrary bash command string> and sending output to <my email address> when online.
2015-02-12 16:26:27,483 - INFO - Running <arbitrary bash command string> and sending output to <my email address> when online.
```

What is causing the second logger.info() to print twice, and only once formatted properly?

I have another script that logs perfectly, no idea what I've done here. (Copy/pasted the logging setup section to be safe)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using loggers at different levels of your code? It sounds like the log messages could be propagating upwards. Try adding

```
logger.propagate = False
```

after you add the handler. You can check out the python docs for a more detailed explanation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate), but the relevant text below sounds exactly like what you're seeing.

> Note If you attach a handler to a logger and one or more of its ancestors, it may emit the same record multiple times. In general, you should not need to attach a handler to more than one logger - if you just attach it to the appropriate logger which is highest in the logger hierarchy, then it will see all events logged by all descendant loggers, provided that their propagate setting is left set to True. A common scenario is to attach handlers only to the root logger, and to let propagation take care of the rest.